# Manually Removed Joomla Component but Title Still Showing Up in Extension Manager

Tags: joomla, components, admin

I had a component cause a bunch of errors at installation in my Joomla website.  I tried the normal way of removing it by visiting the extension manager and clicking uninstall.  This did not work, so I visited these two locations and deleted all the files:

`../administrator/components/com_badcomponentname`

`../components/com_badcomponentname`

I then went into phpmyadmin and dropped all the tables that were associated with `com_badcomponentname`.

The only thing that is left is the listing in the extension manager.  I want to be 100% done with this component, but the name still shows up.  I can disable the listing and that gets it out of the components drop down list in the admin panel.  Where can I go to manually remove the reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that you dropped all the tables that were associated with the component, however if it is still showing in the Extension Manager, then go back into PhpMyAdmin, go into the table `jos_extensions` (**jos** being the prefix which may be different for you) and remove the reference in there too

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would want to to a search on all tables for the name of the component with or without the prefix `com_`.

Also inspecting the install SQL files would give you a better idea if you deleted all the associated tables.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, based on @Valentin Despa's answer, I grep'd the full SQL dump of the site, and found the stale menu items in the `jos_menu` table.