# In Joomla why is jevent component still showing in administrator menu after I disabled it?

Tags: joomla

In Joomla I  used the jevent component. After disabling it I still see the jevent link in my administrator menu on the backend. Why? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Check out the answer by @Lodder here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014347/manually-removed-joomla-component-but-title-still-showing-up-in-extension-manage

Answer (score 0):

Please check out joomla menu table for this. If you are not able to find the jevent entry in menu table then do custom entry for jevent component.You need to provide the component_id in that table.

You will get the component_id from the extension table.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you have disabled the core component and not just a module/plugin. Then check your Joomla! menu items table and look for any relating to com_jevents and remove them accordingly.

You may also find the JEvents Cleaninstall script useful to reset your JEvents installation:

https://www.jevents.net/docs/item/installation-problems